# Having an issue using mailer.php

Tags: php, email, contact-form, http-status-code-405

I'm currently using a mailer.php file for a minimal contact form

However I have noticed recently then when submitting the form, I am getting the following error;

**HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used.**

My mailer.php file is the following

```
<?php
$email_to = "admin@mydomain.co.uk";
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email_from = $_POST["admin@mydomain.co.uk"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
$email_subject = "Feedback from website";
$headers = "From: " . $email_from . "\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . $email_from . "\n";
$message = "Name: ". $name . "\r\nMessage: " . $message;

ini_set("sendmail_from", $email_from);
$sent = mail($email_to, $email_subject, $message, $headers, "-f" .$email_from);
if ($sent)
{
header("Location: https://www.mydomain.co.uk/thankyou.html/");
} else {
echo "There has been an error sending your message. Please try later.";
}
?>
```

The form using this file has the following form tag

```
<form method="post" action="mailer.php">
```

PHP is not my strong point so I'm not sure why this maybe happening. The form itself does not have a captcha field. Could spam be the root of the issue?

I'd appreciate anyone who can shed this light on this for me

Comment: It looks like your web server is configured not to accept POST requests. That's very strange, but you could test it by changing `method="get"` in your form tag. It's not a good solution, but will at least allow you to check that that is the problem. If that works, you should then check *why* your server is not allowing POST requests.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried replacing the post with get and then got the following error: 

HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

Comment: This sounds like your web server is just not configured properly at all, i.e. this is nothing to do with your script. Go read your web server's docs.